# How to get daily standard division by agent?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the daily standard division for each agent, so that first group the agent and date and get the sale count each agent and day wise count then apply the std function. but I am getting an incorrect answer. I think want to use the loop function in this scenario.

```
std = aug_sales.groupby(['Agent','Date'])['Device'].agg(['count']).reset_index()
std.groupby("Agent").apply(np.std)
```

```
Agent    Date          Device
12       01/02/2020    4233     
12       01/02/2020    4123     
12       03/02/2020    4314
12       05/02/2020    4134
12       19/02/2020    5341
12       19/02/2020    52141
12       19/02/2020    24111
12       26/02/2020    24001
12       28/02/2020    111
13       19/02/2020    12141
13       26/02/2020    4224
13       26/02/2020    4222
13       28/02/2020    9563
```

```
output table
Agent   daily_std
12         0.76


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/065Ie.png
```

Comment: In your picture is `for Agent=12 -> 0.763763` what is same like output from `std.groupby("Agent").apply(np.std)`

Comment: So wht need for `Agent=12 -> 1.675` ?

Comment: Do you mean standard *deviation?*

Comment: @jezrael , sry i changed now